# Postfix archive preserving Bcc with X-Envelope-To - cleanup confidential X-Envelope-To with Lmtp

Tags: postfix, archive

Bcc'ing the archive@domain.tld user, we do *not* want people to receive that Bcc list, apart from the archive@domain.tld "user".

## Goal

1. We want to archive all mails going through postfix, sent and received.
   The setup uses:

- postfix,
- dovecot authentication with Pam (pulling from Ldap) users,
- and delivery to the mailboxes via *Dovecot's LMTP*.

2. We want to include the Bcc recipients in the message archive.
3. We do *not* want people to receive that Bcc list, apart from the archive@domain.tld "user".

## Trial

1. Using always_bcc = archive@domain.tld
   Works.
   But the Bcc recipiets (which as per rights are in the envelope as RCPT TO and not in a header) get lost.
2. Using:
   (as per [What options are there to archive Postfix email and preserve any BCC information in the header](https://serverfault.com/questions/59527/what-options-are-there-to-archive-postfix-email-and-preserve-any-bcc-information))

```
main.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/prepend.pcre
```

while the pcre expression is:

```
prepend.pcre
/(.+)/          PREPEND X-Envelope-To: $1
```

*which works like a charm*:
my message stored has the headers To:; Cc; X-Envelope-To.
If any day we need to dig into it, we can know who received the message even in Bcc.
(NB: the X-Envelope-To includes the To and Cc people, pas well as the external domains recipients).

3. To eliminate the X-Envelope-To:
   For sending out:

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks.pcre
```

With the contents:

```
smtp_header_checks.pcre
/^X-Envelope-To:/               IGNORE
```

All ok until there.

## Problem

To eliminate the X-Envelope-To for emails not leaving the server.
I did:

```
lmtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/lmtp_header_checks.pcre

lmtp_header_checks.pcre
/^X-Envelope-To:/               IGNORE
```

But this is not selective, even archive@domain.tld looses the header that was "saved" the Bcc list.

*I cannot find a way to the that header check selective since it only evaluates the line itself and cannot use the recipient to make a condition (even using the "if" of the pcre).*
(http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html)

Is there any variable that can be used ?
A thought was to:
include "archive@domain.tld" in the X-Envelope-To header prepended,
in the lmtp_header_checks.pcre, include something like: archive@domain.tld not equal to $LMTP_DELIVERY_RECIPIENT
Delivered-To or X-Delivered-To remain a separate header that the pcre cannot evaluate as a variable.

Otherwise is there a way to have lmtp trigger some milter ?
And a simple lmtp_milter filter I can use for that ?

Been chasing for days in all docs possible,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh YES !
Thanks you so much.

The sieve langugage will not allow iteration over multiple `X-Envelope-To` headers.
So one needs to pass it to an external program.

Here is what I came up with:

```
require "fileinto";
require "imap4flags";
require ["editheader", "envelope"];
require "vnd.dovecot.filter";
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES"
{
   fileinto "Junk";
   stop;
}
if envelope :is "to" "archive@bogo.ovh" {
   filter "EnvelopeToBcc.sh";
} else {
   deleteheader "X-Envelope-To";
}
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# Store mail in a variable
# input stream
mail=`cat /dev/stdin`
# Extract headers
envelope=$(echo "$mail" | formail -x X-Envelope-To | tr -d '\015')
tos=$(echo "$mail" | formail -x To  | tr -d '\015')
copies=$(echo "$mail" | formail -x Cc  | tr -d '\015')

# Loop excluding the To: fields and concatenate in variable
bcc=""
for i in $envelope; do
        if [[ ${tos} != *"${i}"* && ${copies} != *"${i}"* ]];then
                bcc="${bcc} ${i},"
        fi
done
# Eliminate trailing comma
bcc=$(echo $bcc | sed s/,$//)
# Add Bcc header to mail 
echo "${mail}" | formail -a "Bcc: $bcc"
```

If you open the archive with any MUA you can see the bcc rebuilt.
NB: script a bit longer but it avoids duplication of the To people in the Bcc list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sieve language.

Since your mail is delivered via LMTP to Dovecot, you will have all addressing and header editing capabilities there, with a whole bunch of more complex logic capabilities than those offered by simple Postfix header checks.

If you are not using Pigeonhole sieve yet, you may need to enable it as a Dovecot plugin, enable the extensions you need in your script, and configure a suitable script.

```
# step1 enable sieve (append to $mail_plugins to *add*)
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
# step2 enable sieve extensions, as required (prefix with + to *add*)
plugin {
    sieve_extensions = +editheader
}
# step3 configure the path a of a script to be executed
```

Then in a script executed globally, or specifically for users that shall not see the envelope address, delete the header - unless delivering to the archive mailbox:

```
require ["editheader", "envelope"];
if not envelope :is "to" "archive@example.com" {
    deleteheader "X-Envelope-To";
}
```