# Dovecot sieve concatenate heqders

Tags: dovecot, sieve, headers

## Setup

- postfix forwards all mails to an archive@domain user via `always_bcc`,
- postfix saves all the RCPT TO in `X-Envelope-To` headers to perserve the bcc recipients,
- postfix deletes `X-Envelope-To` for smtp transfers out for privacy reasons,
- postfix delivers messages to dovecot via `lmtp`.
- dovecot uses a sieve script to flush the `X-Envelope-To` for all users except archive@domain.

## Problem

There is one `X-Envelope-To` for each `RCPT TO` initially.
So I would like the sieve script to add a single `Bcc` header concatenating several `X-Envelope-To` values.

```
require "fileinto";
require "imap4flags";
require ["editheader", "envelope"];
require "regex";
require ["variables","mime","foreverypart"];


if envelope :is "to" "archive@domain" {
   concat = """"";
   foreverypart {
        if header :regex "X-Envelope-To" "(.*)" {
        concat = ${concat}  "${1}";
        }
   }
   addheader "Bcc" "${1}";

} else {
   deleteheader "X-Envelope-To";
}
```

Which does not work...

Any easy way to do that in sieve ?
Or no other way than an external script ?
Or perhaps postfix could concatenate all that but that means a milter ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: foreverypart is for looping over MIME parts, but you are looking for multiple headers in the main message, right?

Comment: yes,  exactly: I am trying to iterate over the headers; I thought perhaps there was a way to use the same function but does not seem so.

Comment: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/Extprograms: external sieve script may be the simplest with a simple bash script ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postfix archive preserving Bcc with X-Envelope-To - cleanup confidential X-Envelope-To with Lmtp](https://serverfault.com/questions/1077995/postfix-archive-preserving-bcc-with-x-envelope-to-cleanup-confidential-x-envel)

Comment: Yes, I put the link to my own post as answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See other post.
One needs an external sieve script in Bash.
See proposal in:

[Postfix archive preserving Bcc with X-Envelope-To - cleanup confidential X-Envelope-To with Lmtp](https://serverfault.com/questions/1077995/postfix-archive-preserving-bcc-with-x-envelope-to-cleanup-confidential-x-envel)